# Setting the namespace in XAML

Tags: xaml, namespaces

Suppose I have a top-level `ResourceDictionary` element in a XAML file with no C# code-behind. How can I put this element in a specific namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler than I had thought:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeClassName"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can -- but I've never seen this done.

What I *have* seen is putting ResourceDictionary XAML files in a directory structure in an assembly, and getting it via the Pack URI syntax.

Dr. WPF has an interesting post on getting ResourceDictionaries in code [here](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/10/Default.aspx).